# Dynamic root folder doesn't work for *.php nginx

Tags: php, nginx, configuration

When I am trying to browse http://exmaple.dev.local/test.html Nginx serve static file 'test.html', but when I am trying "index.php" it's not serving it.
**What I am doing wrong?**

The error is 404 "No input file specified." and log says:

```
test location: ~ "\.php$"
using configuration "\.php$"
http cl:-1 max:1048576
rewrite phase: 3
post rewrite phase: 4
generic phase: 5
generic phase: 6
generic phase: 7
access phase: 8
access phase: 9
post access phase: 10
try files phase: 11
http init upstream, client timer: 0
epoll add event: fd:13 op:3 ev:80000005
http script copy: "/var/www/"
http script capture: ""
http script copy: "/webroot/"
http script copy: "/var/www/"
http script capture: ""
http script copy: "/webroot/"
http script copy: "QUERY_STRING"
fastcgi param: "QUERY_STRING: "
http script copy: "REQUEST_METHOD"
http script var: "GET"
fastcgi param: "REQUEST_METHOD: GET"
http script copy: "CONTENT_TYPE"
fastcgi param: "CONTENT_TYPE: "
http script copy: "CONTENT_LENGTH"
fastcgi param: "CONTENT_LENGTH: "
http script copy: "/var/www/"
http script capture: ""
http script copy: "/webroot/"
http script copy: "SCRIPT_FILENAME"
http script var: "/var/www//webroot/"
fastcgi param: "SCRIPT_FILENAME: /var/www//webroot/"
http script copy: "SCRIPT_NAME"
http script var: "/index.php"
fastcgi param: "SCRIPT_NAME: /index.php"
```

My nginx conf is:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name "~^(.*)\.dev\.local$";

#if directory doesn't exist
if (!-d /var/www/$1/webroot/) {
    rewrite . http://dev.local redirect;
}
root /var/www/$1/webroot/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

autoindex on; 
rewrite_log on;
open_file_cache off;

#cake beauty URLs
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
location ~* \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param ENVIRONMENT "bar";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use positional variables (`$1`) in `root` directive. Define named variable.

```
server_name "~^(?<domain>.+)\.dev\.local$";
...
root /var/www/$domain/webroot/;
...
```

Here the problem in regex location where `$1` variable is resetted to empty string.

Comment: Not really. That's how variables works in nginx. They are expanded at last moment. And, btw, what would you expect in `$1` variable if you happen to have `location ~* ^/(.*)\.php$`?

Comment: that's true. Thanks a lot one more time=)